# bash_profile white font bold to normal

Tags: bash, color, font

```
# my .bash_profile
function parse_git_branch {
    git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"

PS1="\w$YELLOW \$(parse_git_branch)$WHITE\$ "
```

for some reason the final `$` and all of the text after that (what I actually type into the terminal) is now a **bold** white color.

I want it to be normal text-weight and white. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My prompt uses `\[\033[00m\]` to go back to the terminal's default color setting. In your case, the `1;` is what is activating "bright".  If you change it to `0;` you should get the "non-bright" white, no matter what your terminal's default color setting is (note that "non-bright" white is usually actually gray, and probably the default).

Answer (score 2):

The text is bold and white because you asked it to be.  Your `WHITE` code is asking for, well, white.  What you probably want is something more like:

```
RESET="\[\033[00m\]"
```

Then use that instead of `WHITE`.